# Make sure ajax success function is happening after $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm trying to speed up some of my sites by moving around the ajax calls

The situation is as follows:

I have a page with some canvas in it + other data.

When the page is requested the 'other data' is loaded. In $(document).ready(); I have a function which gets the data for the canvas. This is done using ajax.

I'm wondering if I could make the ajax call before the $(document).ready() but the success of the ajax call( ie rendering the canvas) only when the dom is ready.

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/someurl'
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            startDrawOnCanvas(stage, response.data);
        }
    });
}
```

This works, but I'd like something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/someurl'
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        //only fire once dom is ready for it
        startDrawOnCanvas(stage, response.data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* do;

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/someurl'
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //will fire once dom is ready for it
            startDrawOnCanvas(stage, response.data);
        });
    }
});
```

... jQuery will detect whether `$(document).ready()` has already ran, and run the callback immediately if it has. Alternately, it'll defer it like it always does.

Comment: Didn't know that. Is there a reference to it?

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić  ready 'pseudo' event use a promise (deferred object readyList) resolved manually even the pseudo event is already done

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić: See http://api.jquery.com/ready/, paragraph starting with "There is also..."

Comment: not that, part with deferring callback execution until DOM is ready